# PHP javascript conversion

Tags: php, javascript, getjson

I am trying to push javascript through PHP and was thinking if this is even possible....

I defined an array in php:

```
$some_date = ["Date.UTC(2008,1,9)", ....];

echo json_encode = ($some_date);
```

on the client side I call

```
$.getJSON(....){
....
}
```

I get data as "Date.UTC(2008,1,9)"
how can I strip out the " without looping through the whole array?

Comment: `echo json_encode = ($some_date)`? What's that supposed to do?

Comment: Can you be more clear please. What data are you trying to extract from the json string?

Comment: I meant echo json_encode($some_date) It is suppose to encode array in JSON format so that I can use the json object on client side to extract individual objects for plugging into charting library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think a simple solution for your issue exists, if you want to keep using "json_encode()"...

Instead, if your array is as simple as it seems, why don't you build your JSON object yourself?

```
$some_date = ["Date.UTC(2008,1,9)", "Date.UTC(2008,1,10)"];
$json_encoded = '['. implode(', ', $some_date) .']';
echo $json_encoded;
```

Simple, clean and nice!

Answer (score 1):

I can't see why you shouldn't iterate the array, but you can join the array then use regexp to match the dates and then again slit it.

This can both be done server side:

```
$some_date = ["Date.UTC(2008,1,9)", ....];
$some_date_string = implode("|", $some_date);
$some_date_string = preg_replace_callback(/Date\.UTC\(([0-9]{4}),([0-9]{1,2}),([0-9]{1,2})\)/g, function(matches) {
    // matches[0] = year
    // matches[1] = month/day - dont know your order (y.m.d/y.d.m)
    // matches[2] = month/day
}, $some_date_string);

$some_date = explode("|", $some_date);
```

And client side:

```
$.getJSON('path.php', function(arr) {
    var arr = arr.join('|').replace(/Date\.UTC\(([0-9]{4}),([0-9]{1,2}),([0-9]{1,2})\)/g, function(_, a, b, c) {
        // a = year
        // b = month/day - dont know your order (y.m.d/y.d.m)
        // c = month/day
    }).split('|');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the replace method to remove double quotes.

```
var new_date = some_date.replace(/"/g, '');
```